# Sourcing Informative Priors from an already conducted Empirical Study in brms package in R

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian, mixed-models, brms

I am conducting two studies (with 15 participants) and my study is based on two already conducted studies with a very similar objective and method. One of the studies contain only the results, and one of them have data available online. This is on face and emotion perception with static faces and dynamic faces. I would like to use informed priors and conduct bayesian statistical inferencing to understand if the predictors (social anxiety) predict the outcome (sensitivity to threatening face expressions). I have multiple trials per participant (and the num of trials vary for each) so I would like to do a mixed effects modelling with informed priors based on the the two studies.

Could someone perhaps help me understand the syntax of the set_priors () function in brms? Or help me with how to source those from the previous studies?

Thank you so much in advance! Please let me know if you need any more info on my study.

Any directions towards some helpful materials would also be very appreciated! I have been scouring statistics articles and have understood the whats and whys but not exactly how to do it. I have used uninformed priors before and I am comfortable with brms (but not with setting my own priors).

Comment: Very interesting question.  It might be helpful to post it on Stat Exchange: https://stats.stackexchange.com/